# Why StyleBundle css is rendered as html doctype in my ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why my StyleBundle is rendered as html instead of minimize style? the same code "@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")" render it correct at any other page except my login page. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to check. First check the definition of your bundle: check name, path and if all files exists. If you are sure that everything is 
correct check applicatio errors: you could install elmah or handle Application_Error in Global.asax. The page you see instead of css it is error page or main page, so there is an error inbundle definition or routing

Comment: thanks Garath, i check again with Firebug and realize the "Authentication & Authorization" in my web.config is giving a HTTP 302 to the bundle css. After removing that folder from Authorize only area, it's all good. thanks!